# О постановке запятой перед ИЛИ

Tags: пунктуация

Первый человек утверждает, что в предложении «*Я смогу сесть где угодно(,) или места будут обозначены заранее?*» запятая в указанном месте не ставится, ссылаясь на самый последний пункт ([см.](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=351)).

Второй утверждает, что запятая здесь нужна, аргументируя ответ с предоставленной ссылкой так: «нет, тут вопросы разные по значению. должно быть кто и где? зачем и почему? и т. д.».

Честно говоря, я не могу понять смысл такого ответа. Вроде бы ясно, что это просто примеры, а в самом пункте в правилах об этом ни слова.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос о постановке запятой перед ИЛИ (в ССП при наличии вопросительной интонации) решается неоднозначно и в теории, и в практике:

**1) У Розенталя и Лопатина:** Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?;

**2) У Ткаченко:** Перед союзом ИЛИ, соединяющим части сложносочинённого предложения, построенные по модели вопросительного, побудительного или восклицательного предложения, Запятая ставится, т. к. союз ИЛИ способствует членению предложения на две части (о чём свидетельствует пауза между ними), например: ...Дядя влюблён в вас, или нет? (Дост.)

[Знаки препинания в сложносочинённом предложении | hi-edu.ru](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook614/01/part-003.htm)

**Можно попробовать объяснить ситуацию следующим образом:**

У разделительного союза ИЛИ могут быть разные значения, например:

А) «Изредка раздастся выстрел или ракета осветит местность». Нет запятой и паузы. Здесь союз ИЛИ имеет **значение  чередования**, нет взаимоисключающего значения,  два события в данной ситуации **связаны между собой** как нарушение спокойствия.

Б) «Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя»? Ставится запятая, делается пауза. В этом случае союз ИЛИ имеет значение  **взаимоисключения,** речь идет о несовместимых событиях, поэтому **нет темы их объединения**.

**Решение задач**

Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам? Нет паузы и запятой, объединяющая тема: каким образом мы встретимся.

Я смогу сесть где угодно, или места будут обозначены заранее? Ситуации взаимоисключающие,  есть пауза и запятая.

Comment: *>>Б) "Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя?" Ставится запятая, делается пауза.*     Запятая НЕ ставится, а уж пауза здесь (и во всех других случаях) ну совсем ни при чем. ССП, обе основы — вопросительные предложения.

Comment: М. Булгаков: "Римского прокуратора называть — игемон. Других слов не говорить. Смирно стоять. Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя"? В разных изданиях пишут по-разному, в учебниках также нет единого мнения. Вообще говоря,  прочитать предложение можно  с паузой и без паузы: 1) Ты пОнял меня, или удАрить тебя?  (пауза, два повышения голоса, два вопроса). 2) Ты понял меня или удАрить тебя? (нет паузы, одно повышение голоса, общий вопрос). Мне кажется, что здесь как раз тот случай, когда предложения не связываются общей вопросительной интонацией в единое целое и между ними делается пауза.

Comment: §104. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении

...

2. Запятая перед союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения:

...

г) выражены двумя вопросительными, или двумя восклицательными, или двумя побудительными предложениями, например: *Ты понял меня или ударить тебя?* (Булгаков)...

Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
М.: ЧеРо, 1999
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm

При чем здесь паузы?!

Comment: А как Вы думаете, чем мотивируется это правило, то есть какой в нем смысл? (А паузы к постановке знаков препинания имеют самое прямое отношение, русская пунктуация основана на трех принципах: семантическом,интонационном и грамматическом. Даже по своему названию знак препинания обозначает остановку в речи, то есть паузу).

Comment: На трех-то на трех, но вы чересчур выпячиваете один из них. Который, собственно, самый последний. Не счесть в русском языке фраз, в которых на месте интонационных пауз знаки не ставятся, а ставятся как раз в местах, где пауз нет. Так что рулит именно структура предложения, синтаксис. "Интонация" может завести на ложный путь, что, собственно, мы и видим. Не случайно в справочниках (и в учебниках!) интонация практически не упоминается.

Comment: Не каждая пауза обозначается запятой, поэтому лучше считать, что русская пунктуация основана на интонационно-грамматическом принципе. Но вот что интересно: именно с помощью интонации можно решить самые трудные задачи (как в нашем случае), также интонация официально считается основным средством связи в БСП. Но Вы так и не ответили не первый вопрос: почему при наличии одиночных союзов И/ИЛИ в ССП  с вопросительной или восклицательной интонацией не ставится запятая?

Comment: Ваши дискуссии какие-то странные. В правиле же чётко всё сказано, но человек, который проверял моё предложение, говорит, что запятая здесь нужна. Причины, по которым он так считает, я процитировал (см. в самом посте). И да, здесь надо как-то всё-таки к одному варианту прийти, а не ходить вокруг да около.

Comment: Если Вы сдаете работу на ПРОВЕРКУ, то запятую ставить не надо, так как  такие работы  должны соответствовать академическим правилам. (Здесь мы имеем  ССП, в котором два предложения при наличии одиночного союза ИЛИ объединены общей вопросительной интонацией). Второй  же человек, по-видимому, перепутал ССП и СПП, где запятая также не ставится, если однородные придаточные с союзными словами кто и где? зачем и почему? соединены союзом ИЛИ. Думаю, что эти люди просто рассуждали о разных видах предложений.

Comment: Что касается дискуссии, то она о том, есть ли исключения из этого правила для союза ИЛИ, так как даже в классических текстах встречаются варианты письма (с запятой и без запятой). Но Вам, я думаю, эта дискуссия  не очень интересна, в Вашем случае лучше пользоваться простым (вернее, упрощенным) правилом, по которому запятая НЕ СТАВИТСЯ.

Comment: При чем здесь классические тексты? "Авторская пунктуация" – это такой темный лес, что туда лучше и не соваться. "Но Вы так и не ответили не первый вопрос: почему при наличии одиночных союзов И/ИЛИ в ССП с вопросительной или восклицательной интонацией не ставится запятая?" – потому что так в справочниках, вот и всё. Всё же очень просто.

Comment: А в чем тогда проблема? Пользователь 1 нашел  правило, где ясно сказано, что запятая не пишется, и указал на это пользователю 2. Но  вот пользователь 3 почему-то стал это правило  оспаривать, причем настолько успешно, что пользователь 2 также стал сомневаться в своем выборе, а почему? Правила Лопатина - небольшой по объему и всем доступный ресурс, отчего  же все вопросы не решаются там быстро и просто?  Если есть четкое правило,  то ЗАЧЕМ его нарушать, выдумывать авторскую пунктуацию.

Comment: И если этот факт не объяснять и не обращать на него внимания, то вопрос о запятой перед союзом   ИЛИ  будет появляться постоянно. Потому что даже чисто интуитивно  разные  предложения  с ИЛИ звучат по-разному. В конце концов, ИЛИ - это разделительный союз, ему сложно во всех случаях выполнять соединительную функцию.

Comment: Что более удивительно, учебник рассчитан для поступающих в вузы. Если абитуриент будет основываться на этом правиле, скорее всего запятую ему сочтут за ошибку. Я как-то обращался на Грамму.ру с этим вопросом. Они ответили, что ,по-видимому, это ошибка допущенная Ткаченко. Свой ответ  они аргументировали ,опираясь на справочники Лопатина и Розенталя.

Comment: Я повторно задал этот вопрос Грамоте.ру с просьбой дать исчерпывающий ответ. Пока не получил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Поправилам, перед «или» запятая ставится, если этот союз используется в сложном предложении, где связываются 2 или несколько простых предложений. Вывод: запятая нужна.

Comment: По каким это правилам? Приведите источник.