# Запятая перед союзом "или"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: "Вы будете что-нибудь заказывать или мне подойти позже?"

Вопрос: нужна ли запятая перед союзом "или"?

Мне кажется, нужна, но я сомневаюсь.
"Вы будете заказывать, или мне (стоит) подойти позже?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Вы будете заказывать, или мне (стоит) подойти позже?***

1. Союз ИЛИ не так прост, как кажется, чтобы  отвечать на такой вопрос, нисколько не задумываясь.

Да, **есть правило** на эту тему – кстати, **ссылку** надо на него давать, а не просто цитировать (недостаток ответа): Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133 § 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении

Пункт 3. Запятая перед соединительным и **разделительным** союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят: 1) **вопросительные предложения**: Это кто такие и что им надобно? (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда? Когда состоится конференция и какова повестка дня? Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?

2. В приведенных у Розенталя примерах  **запятую действительно не хочется ставить.** А вот в заданном предложении **пауза хорошо слышится**, вот и автор вопроса нам подсказывает: *Вы бУдете заказывать,  или мне **(стоит)** подойти пОзже?*  Как-то неудобно читать всё это **в одну фразу**. Да и отношения между предложениями **неоднородные**, то есть переставить их местами нельзя.А если переставить нельзя, то и объединять нежелательно, есть такое правило в грамматике.
3. Поэтому предлагается **поставить запятую**  ввиду неоднородности предложений и наличия паузы в речи. Эта тема  (союз ИЛИ) обсуждалась  на форуме, хотя к единому мнению, разумеется,  не пришли. Там давалась ссылка **на учебник Ткаченко**, где относительно союза ИЛИ  было особое замечание.
   [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423401/О-постановке-запятой-перед-ИЛИ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423401/%D0%9E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98)
   http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook614/01/part-003.htm

Впрочем, решили, что Ткаченко ошибается, а что еще можно решить.  Конечно, унификация дело хорошее и удобное, и нам хочется поскорее стать грамотными.  Да только такая **простота обедняет нашу речь**, об этом тоже не стоит забывать.

4. Ну и последний довод

Вы считаете союз ИЛИ **разделительным?** А ведь он еще может быть пояснительным и присоединительным. Например: *Он вернулся в одиннадцать часов, или около этого.  И детей оставили, или почти что оставили, в покое. В этих заведениях можно было купить всё, или почти всё, но цены были аховые*. [Дина Гаврилова, 2018]

И если оппоненты будут категорически против запятой, то почему бы нам не отнести ИЛИ к **присоединительным союзам**.  Если автор хочет **подчеркнуть паузу**, то это вполне законный прием.

Answer (score 2):

> Запятая перед одиночными соединительными и разделительными союзами – и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо – не ставится в следующих случаях: .....

> д) в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят вопросительные
> предложения:
>
> Вы придёте ко мне или я должен зайти к вам?